# Convert list to group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question: i want to use a code like this:

```
var groups = shouldBeGroup ? items.GroupBy(p => p.Prop) : <a group with all items>
foreach(var gr in groups)...
```

How to implement the second part? I would like a group with all items but GroupBy return many groups based on the specified property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
items.Group(p => p.Prop)
```

This will return a collection of `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TProp,TItem>>`

where TProp is the type of the Prop property you are grouping by and TItem is the type of the items.

so the type of your `groups` variable is just that `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TProp,TItem>>` so whatever you assign to it must be of that type. So if `shouldBeGroup` is true then you evaluate `items.GroupBy(p => p.Prop);` that fits (actually it dictates) the type required.

So if shouldBeGroups is false you need an expression that returns something of the same type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TProp,TItem>>`
   `items.GroupBy(i => //here you need to provide a constant value of the same type of p.Prop)`

so an example lets assume that p.Prop is of type string

we would do this

```
var grouped = shouldBeGrouped ? items.GroupBy(p => p.Prop) : items.GroupBy(p => "stringConstant");
```

because you provide a constant value for every item they will all appear in the same group. But rememebr the type of p.Prop will dicate what type you need for the constant value in the second GroupBy expression